# I use == to compare two strings of ':‘ in python, why I get the result of False

Tags: python-2.7

This is the python code:

```
 nr_sign=':'
    with open("1.txt") as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
        print lines[0].split(' ')[0]==nr_sign
```

I have checked that the lines[0].split(' ')[0] is ':' and the type is string, which is the same with nr_sign. But why the result shows lines[0].split(' ')[0]==nr_sign is false? How can I compare this?
Thanks very much!

Comment: `==` Compares not types, but _values_. Apparently, the first line in the file is not starts with ': '. Hard to tell exactly without input data.

Comment: Try printing the `repr` of both strings to see if they're actually identical.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, more info is needed here.  If you could post the line being compared, the the lines[0].split... , that might help troubleshoot it.  Simply put, you're getting a result of False because the two strings aren't equal.  (Sorry, I get a "duh" here, but you did ask why you get False for the result)

Comment: Asking for more info might be a helpful comment, but it isn't really an answer. When you have enough reputation you will be able to leave comments.